# ASPX GridView edit clicked cell only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am binding data in a DataTable to a GridView.

The result is a simple table with 5 columns and 3 rows.

**What I want to achieve is:**

If an user clicks on a cell in the GridView, the selected cell should become editable (with a textbox). In that textbox the user should have to possibility to enter new value and save it to the database.

**What I've achieved so far is:**

I followed this tutorial: http://www.dotnetlogix.com/Article/aspnet/80/How-to-make-GridView-Individual-Cells-Selectable.html

I managed to make the cells clickable, when clicking the cell the background color becomes red:

[image]

With that tutorial I also managed to get the ColumnIndex and RowIndex.

So I was able to do: GridView.SetEditRow(RowIndex);

**Then my result became:**

[image]

This is almost what I want, but not 100%. The SetEditRow edits the whole row, but I need to edit the clicked cell which is based on a row and column index.

Can anyone help me further please?

I've followed some other tutorials as well, but without result.

Comment: Are you using seperate gridview to render each cell

Comment: `Binding`, `DataTable` and `GridView` are not words I associate with [tag:asp-classic].

Answer (score 1):

I tried this a few years ago and ran into a few issues, I don't recall all of them off the top of my head right now. What I ended up doing was using a repeater instead of a gridview to build a table. Since I'm writing the HTML I have more control over things. The table contained both a dig tag for the static value and a text input for the edit value. I used jquery to show and hide when needed. I then used ajax to post the changes back. This was a lot of work, but it ended up working out ok. Hope this helps.